# Process is Terminated due to StackOverFlowException C#

Tags: c#, exception

This is my code. I am not able to figure out why this code is giving 'Process is Terminated due to StackOverFlowException'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SadiSDAL4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrivateVehical privateV = new PrivateVehical("001");
            PrivateVehical pVehical = (PrivateVehical)privateV.Clone();
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", privateV.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", pVehical.name);
            privateV.name = "Sadia's Car";
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", privateV.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", pVehical.name);
            pVehical.name = "Waheed's Car";
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", privateV.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", pVehical.name);
            Console.WriteLine(privateV.GetHashCode().ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(pVehical.GetHashCode().ToString());
            PublicVehical publicV = new PublicVehical("002");
            Console.WriteLine(publicV.id);
            PublicVehical pubVehi = (PublicVehical)publicV.Clone();
            Console.WriteLine("Cloned : {0}", pubVehi.id);
        }
    }
    abstract class Vehical
    {
        private string vehicalId = "01";
        public string name = "Car_1";
        public Vehical(string id)
        {
            this.vehicalId = id;
        }
        public string id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { this.vehicalId = id; }
        }
        public abstract Vehical Clone();
    }
    class PrivateVehical : Vehical
    {
        public PrivateVehical(string id)
            : base(id)
        {

        }
        public override Vehical Clone()
        {
            return (Vehical)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
    class PublicVehical : Vehical
    {
        public PublicVehical(string id)
            : base(id)
        {

        }
        public override Vehical Clone()
        {
            return (Vehical)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output. 
[image]
Can someone explain what is the cause of it ? Why it is working in first part & not in the other ?

Comment: What an ironical exception! By the way, your getter is incorrect.

Comment: The exception first occurs when you call `publicV.id`.  If you were to do `privateV.id` after you create it, you would see the exception.

Comment: I had same issue with one of my method. I found that I was calling itself inside a function, making it recursive non-ending call.

Answer (score 34):

Take a look at this code:

```
    public string id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { this.vehicalId = id; }
    }
```

Specifically `get { return id; }`. You are returning property to itself, causing SO error.

Is this what you intended:

```
    public string id
    {
        get { return this.vehicalId; }
        set { this.vehicalId = value; }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your minute observation, it saved my time. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Your error is occurring on this line of code

```
Console.WriteLine(publicV.id);
```

When you try to get the value of a property from your `publicV` variable it is calling the getter on the base class.
In your case that's this block in the `Vehicle` class

```
 public string id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { this.vehicalId = id; }
    }
```

However, when the `get` is called it executes `return id;`. So it once again calls the getter for the id property, which executes the `return id;` line of code again.
So effectively that line of code is calling itself over and over with no resolution, creating your Stack Overflow issue.
(If you're not familiar with this concept see [Recursion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx))

Take a look at the Vehicle's id property again. 
You have the right idea for the `set` version, you assign the value to the `vehicleId` property. That is also where you should be getting it from.
I expect that if you change the getter to
`get { return this.vehicleId; }`
that would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Debugging the code shows you have a cut and paste error.

```
        public string id
        {
            // having this set to id causes endless recursion
            //get { return id; }

            //use this instead
            get { return vehicalId; }
            set { this.vehicalId = id; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is caused by this definition below:

```
public string id
{
  get { return id; }
  set { this.vehicalId = id; }
}
```

That is because the get call is returning a call to itself, that is, get Id calls get Id, which calls get Id, over and over until you run out of memory and get a StackOverflowException. I guess you meant to do this:

```
public string id
{
  get { return vehicalId; }
  set { this.vehicalId = id; }
}
```

By the way, it feels really accomplishing coming to stackoverflow to get help on debugging a StackOverflowException :)